# Create object from List elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm very sorry the title may not be informative enough, but I don't know how to explain what i'm trying to do in a question.

So, I have an MVC application, and i'm loading my routes from a configuration section in the `Web.config`.

In order to encapsulate all the information I need from the configured elements, I created a RouteModel.

```
IEnumerable<RouteModel> configuredRoutes = RoutingFacade.GetAllRoutes();

foreach(RouteModel route in configuredRoutes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(route.Name, route.Url,
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", managers = route.Managers });
}
```

Ignore the managers key over there.

So far so good, but my problem is this.
My `RouteModel` has a `Constraints` property that returns a `List<ConstraintModel>` with all the configured constraints for that route.
`ConstraintModel` only has two properties, `Name` and `Value`.

As you may know, the `MapRoute` method takes an additional `object` parameter which are the constraints, this object is constructed like this:

`new { constraint1 = value1, constraint2 = value2, .. }`

How can I turn my `List<ConstraintModel>` into something like that?

I really appreciate you take your time to read my problem, thank you very much in advance

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is how will this appear in the querystring. Querystrings are simple name:value *strings*. So you can't represent a complex object in the querystring, so you can't pass it into the action (not as a GET anyway). POST are are different. Is this a GET or a POST or both?

Comment: I'm really sorry I don't understand your concern, but the HTTP Method will be a GET :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the methods of the `RouteCollection` class you will notice there is an `Add` method ([MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx)).

What you can do is you can call it (that is what the `MapRoute` extension method does eventually)
and create an instance of the `Route` class however you wish.

```
Dictionary<string, object> constraints = new Dictionary<string, object>();
// populate your constraints into the constraints dictionary here..

Dictionary<string, object> dataTokens = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dictionary<string, object> defaults = new Dictionary<string, object>();

Route route = new Route(" << url >> ", new MvcRouteHandler())
{
    Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints),
    DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(),
    Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary()
};

routes.Add(route);
```

That way, you have the opportunity to specify `string` - `object` pairs for you constraints.

**EDIT**

Furthermore, if you have any doubts on how to use this method but are well versed in what the `MapRoute` extension method is concerned I suggest you use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to disassemble the assembly which defines `MapRoute` (which is `System.Web.Mvc.dll`) and go step by step and discover the connection between `MapRoute` and `RouteCollection.Add` for yourself.

**EDIT 2 - Concerning Route names**

You can also check the overload `RouteCollection.Add(string name, RouteBase item)`.
That is one way in which you could specify the name of the route.

So basically you could go and do this:

```
routes.Add(" My route with dynamically loaded constraints ", route);
```

Comment: This is a very interesting answer.

How do I specify the name of my route?

Comment: This seems to solve all my concerns, I'm gonna try it and come back with news. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I managed to map the route along with its constraints succesfully, thanks for your help!